# Eclipse RCP config.ini

Tags: eclipse, config, product, rcp

Is it possible to call and use the confi.ini file generated by **RCP product** in **RCP plugin project** ?

In the **Configuration** tab i've added two properies that i want to call and use in my **RCP plugin project** .
The two properties are an **URL** adress and a **KEY**. I've added them in the **config.ini** so when I export my **RCP product** and deploy it later, other users could modify the **KEY** or the **URL**. 
I hope that my post is clear enough !

Thanks in advance.

Ismail

Comment: What do you mean by `RCP plugin project`? Do you mean while you are testing within Eclipse?

Comment: The plugin project is the project where the needed plugins are call and where the source is edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties you define in the `config.ini` can be accessed using the standard `System.getProperty("property-name")` call.

When you are testing an RCP in Eclipse using a `Run Configuration` you can either specify the property in the `Arguments` tab, VM arguments part, using the format:

```
-Dproperty=value
```

Or you can specify a `config.ini` template on the `Configuration` tab. In either case you still use `System.getProperty` to access the value.

Comment: Thanks greg for the asnwer. I've tried your method but it returns : null. The config.ini file is in my product and I want to use it in the plugin project.

Comment: I've added the new properties in the Configuration tab. I want to use those new properties to connect to an API. How to call or use these two properties, so i could connect to the API ? What to add in the VM arguments ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg-449, the method that adds the property in the VM arguments works fine when I run the application in eclipse. But when I export my application and run it from my desktop, it doesn't work. I think it's better to add them in the config.ini, but when i call System.getproperty it returns : null.

Comment: Well greg , it's working. Just some syntax error :). With : System.getProperty, i call and use my config.ini as i want. Thanks a lot.