# Eclipe RCP using custom config file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'd like to use some kind of ini/xml configuration file which can be accessed by the user at any time and change the configuration. Basically we need the ability to let the user change these configs without starting the application, which needs these configs before startup.

My problem is that the file I need are at two places depending on the context:

While developing its inside one of my bundles in a custom directory (something like config/config.ini)

When I export the application, this directory gets placed inside the root of my application folder (so like eclipse/config/config.ini)

So far so good but how do I access this one file while testing and in an exported application?

Because when I do something like this:

```
URL resource = MyCustomClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/config/config.ini");
```

Where **MyCustomClass** is a class in the project the file is in, I can access the file while developing/testing, but this doesnt work in an exported application

While if I do something like:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("my.project.sub");
IPath path = new Path("config/config.ini");
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
```

This also works while in developing but doesnt work in the exported application, I mean the file isnt in the bundle now as it got exported.

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is using the default config.ini properties.

The best way to access is :

```
System.getProperty("propertyeName")
```

You can see : [Eclipse RCP config.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739927/eclipse-rcp-config-ini)